# Weekly calendar records

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, calendar

I want to get records on weekly basis from a table in which i have stored a datetime field.
A mysql query which can identify the **week number** and **week start** and **end date**.

Like shown here in the link.

https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2017

How can i get that record through mysql query with week number, start and end date of that week and the records between start and end date of the week. Not for current or single week. I need them for all past weeks upto records datetime values available in database table..
I.e

```
Week (number to know?) - Start date - end date.

Week 01 -   Start date - January 2, 2017 ---- End date --   January 8, 2017
|-> All records in it.
Week 02 -   Start date - January 9, 2017 ---- End date --   January 15, 2017
|-> All records in it.
```

Comment: First you need to decide if you are using mysql or sql server. They are not the same thing. Then you need to post enough information so others aren't guessing what you want. Table definition, sample data and desired output based on the sample data.

Comment: also be aware that weeknumbers are different for US then for other regions, like europe for example

Comment: Please, give an example of input parameter values and expected result.

Comment: Do you want to get dates of the first and last days of a week,  that specified by year and week number?

Comment: Or do you mean what there is a table with time stamped records in your database and you want to get week number, first and last dates of week for each record?

Comment: @Alexander I need UK based weekly records. Let say it is January and there are four weeks in it. So need mysql query which can separate all 4 weeks records. Which will display start and end date of each week

Comment: @Googler, oh I had not wait your comment and post the answer. Please, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let, there is the `main_table` in your database with some data. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE `main_table` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Date` date NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT main_table 
    (`Date`, Description) 
VALUES 
    ('2017-01-02','The first record'),
    ('2017-01-05','The second record'),
    ('2017-01-11','The third record'),
    ('2017-01-17','The fourth record');
```

Create a user defined function, that returns date of specific day of same week as specified date. Use [CREATE FUNCTION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) syntax:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `GET_DAY_OF_WEEK` (`date`  DATE, `day` TINYINT UNSIGNED) 
RETURNS DATE
BEGIN
    RETURN `date`- INTERVAL WEEKDAY(`date`) + 1 DAY + INTERVAL `day` DAY;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

If your week is started by Monday, then use `1` for Monday and `7` for Sunday. If your week is started by Sunday, then use `0` for Sunday and `6` for Saturday. For example, my week is started by Monday, and I want to get last Wednesday date, then

```
SELECT GET_DAY_OF_WEEK('2017-06-03', 3);
```

returns `'2017-05-31'`.
Thus to get records of `main_table` on weekly, you could use the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    WEEKOFYEAR(`Date`) AS WeekNum,
    GET_DAY_OF_WEEK(`Date`, 1) AS WeekStarted,
    GET_DAY_OF_WEEK(`Date`, 7) AS WeekFinished,
    Description
FROM main_table;
```

The query result will be

```
ID  WeekNum WeekStarted WeekFinished    Description
1   1       2017-01-02  2017-01-08      'The first record'
2   1       2017-01-02  2017-01-08      'The second record'
3   2       2017-01-09  2017-01-15      'The third record'
4   3       2017-01-16  2017-01-22      'The fourth record'
```

Comment: Looks great @Alexander. Let me give it a try Will update you back.

Comment: @Googler, did you try the solution? Are there more questions?

Comment: Buddy not yet. Had one more question on it. I will update you shortly by tomorrow once i start on it. Little busy right now. Will surely catch up with u. Need more assistance from you. Thanks

Comment: How can i number the day names on base of the above records. Like i want all records belonging to monday as 1, tuesday as 2, Wed as 3 and so on.. I have a field datetime to be used as base of the records for filtering.

Comment: @Googler, use [DAYOFWEEK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) method or [DAYNAME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname).

Comment: THanks @Alexander. Why i am not able to get distinct records on base of WEEKOFYEAR. like select distinct DAYOFWEEK(DATE(datetime));

Comment: Used group by instead. Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you please help me with this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44563916/current-day-total-login-time-mysql

Comment: can you give ur 5 mins today please. I need to work on it. :( Would really appreciate it

Answer (score -2):

Learn how to get the weeks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44301682/how-to-show-number-of-week-and-show-date-range-in-php/44301818?noredirect=1#comment75609191_44301818), then to get mysql data between the dates, use this statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM stock WHERE dateColumnName BETWEEN '{$startDate}' AND '{$endDate}'";
```

Ensure the dates are in format 'Y-m-d'.

UPDATE:

Here is the full code that works for me:

```
<?php 
function getStartAndEndDate($week, $year) {
  $dto = new DateTime();
  $dto->setISODate($year, $week);
  $ret['week_start'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
  $dto->modify('+6 days');
  $ret['week_end'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
  return $ret;
} ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Week Number</th>
            <th>From Date</th>
            <th>To Date</th>
        </tr>
<?php 
for($i=1; $i<=52; $i++){
    $week_array = getStartAndEndDate($i,2017);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM stock WHERE on_date BETWEEN '{$week_array['week_start']}' AND '{$week_array['week_end']}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo "<tr>
            <td>Week $i </td>
            <td>".$week_array['week_start']."</td>
            <td>".$week_array['week_end']."</td>
            <td>".$item['id']."</td>
        </tr>"; 
} ?>

</table>
```

Comment: Sorry @Alexander I don't understand your english. But have you tried the code before doing this?

Comment: send requests to MySQL server in `for` loop is not good idea. Sorry for my English. ;)

Comment: Read about parametrised queries

Comment: I think it to be worst because of loop