# Current day total login time mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime, stored-procedures

I am trying to calculate user's login time in hours and mins for current day.

I have my session table as

```
id|  user_id  |  logintime          |logouttime           | isactive
1|  100      |  2017-06-12 22:53:53 |2017-06-13 02:53:53 | 0
2|  100      |  2017-06-13 08:53:53  |2017-06-13 09:13:53 | 0
3|  100      |  2017-06-13 10:53:53 |2017-06-13 11:33:53 | 0
4|  100      |  2017-06-13 11:53:53 |2017-06-13 12:13:53 | 0
5|  100      |  2017-06-13 12:53:53 |NULL (As user is currently logged in)| 1
```

I want a query which can calculate total login day  of current day let say the date is 13 today. One more thing i want to mention is that in Record id 1 it states that user did login at 12-06-2017 but as i need record time of 13 so it will start from 2017-06-13 00:00:00 (as login time of that day).

Thanks in advance. 
EDIT:

So far query i tried which is giving wrong calculation for the id 1 and 5 .
for id 1 it is calculating the minutes of yesterday also and for 5th it is giving null as user is currently logged in

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,logintime,logouttime) FROM `table` WHERE user_id= 17 and DATE(logouttime) = DATE(UTC_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - We're here to help, not to write code for you. Show us what you've tried so far and I'm quite sure someone will help you, but nobody will provide a finished solution for you.

Comment: Okay @Twinfriends. Updating question with queries

Comment: a push in the right direction: look at TIMESTAMPDIFF from mysql

Answer (score 0):

For active sessions you could use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of `logouttime` value. Create view with corrected timestamps to avoid duplicate same select subquery in your query:

```
CREATE VIEW sessions_view AS
SELECT
    user_id, 
    logintime,
    IF(isactive, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, logouttime) AS logouttime
FROM sessions_table;
```

To split sessions that passes from one day to another use `UNION` syntax with conditions. Use [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function to get difference between `logintime` and `logouttime` values. To get aggregated duration that is time data type, use `SUM` aggregate function and [`SEC_TO_TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) to convert seconds to `DATETIME` value:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    DATE(logintime) AS `day`,
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, logintime, logouttime)))
FROM
    (SELECT
        user_id, 
        logintime, 
        IF(DATE(logouttime)>DATE(logintime), TIMESTAMP(DATE(logouttime)), logouttime) AS logouttime
    FROM sessions_view
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        user_id, 
        TIMESTAMP(DATE(logouttime)) AS logintime, 
        logouttime
    FROM sessions_view
    WHERE DATE(logouttime)>DATE(logintime)) splited_sessions
GROUP BY user_id, `day`;
```

If you want to get data for specific date only, then append following `WHERE` clause to the query:

```
WHERE DATE(logintime) = '2017-06-13'
```

Comment: FROM sessions_view WHERE DATE(logintime) = '2017-06-30') splited_sessions GROUP BY user_id, `day`

@Alexander it is not giving me data of date i provided.

Comment: @Googler, this expression belongs to main (external) query, therefore it must to be append directly before `GROUP BY` clause (after `splited_sessions`).

Comment: Thanks dude, There is one issue with this query. Let say today is 2017-07-03 and user has logged in on 2017-07-02 (Where he didn't logged out throughout the day). In this case if i get the records for . 2017-07-03 it is not retruning any thing . Where it should be displaying the time from 2017-07-03 00:00:00 to current time as user has logged in on yesterday. How to fix this?

Comment: @Googler, create session that started 2017-07-02 at 14:30 and finished 2017-07-03 at 11:15. If you run the query without `WHERE DATE(logintime) = '2017-06-13'` then you will see, that there are two sessions: from 2017-07-02 14:30 to 2017-07-03 00:00 and from 2017-07-03 00:00 to 2017-07-03 11:15.

Comment: You are right. But thing is that user hasn't logged out at 2017-07-03 at 11:15 and the finished or logout out column contains the null value. What should i do ?

Comment: @Googler, if `isactive` field is `true` then `logouttime` is equals to current date and time (see `sessions_view` view).